# vb.net distinct value not working

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get distinct values from a string. the string looks like this:

this is richtextbox3's text:

```
121010, 121010, 121011, 121010,
```

And this is my code:

```
' Create a list of integers. 
        Dim date3 As String = RichTextBox3.Text
        Dim dates As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() _
                                         {date3})

        ' Select the unique numbers in the List. 
        Dim distinctDates As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = dates.Distinct()

        Dim output As New System.Text.StringBuilder("Distinct ages:" & vbCrLf)
        For Each age As Integer In distinctDates
            output.AppendLine(age)
        Next

        ' Display the output.
        RichTextBox7.Text = (output.ToString)
    End If
```

but when i run it, i get an error

"Conversion from string "121010, 121010, 121011, 121010, " to type 'Integer' is not valid."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to implicitly convert the string `"121010, 121010, 121011, 121010, "` to an integer here:

```
New Integer() {date3}
```

`New Integer() {...}` creates a new integer array, but you try to add a string `date3` to it.

---

You're probably looking for something like:

```
Dim dates = date3.Split({" "c, ","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) _
                 .Select(Function(i) Int32.Parse(i)) _
                 .Distinct() _
                 .ToList()
```

Comment: So I need to try a different method?

Comment: @user3188226 Yes, I updated my answer with an example